# Is there a way to mark a method as pending to implement in Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Just wondering if you can mark a method as pending to implement in pharo, like you can do in java using "todo"

I'ts really hard for me to keep track of what's complete on pharo without something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this by myself 2 days after asking about it, almost accidentally, just using the context menu option `jump to test method` over a method without any test. Pharo automatically generated an empty test with this:

```
self flag: #toImplement.
self assert: false`
```

the first line, which can be used not only on tests, gives me the behavior I expected as it automatically categorizes the method containing it on a  `flags` category marked with a big `"!"` allowing to easily check at glance which methods are pending.

The second line forces test to fail and be shown on yellow which is pretty useful because if it's empty it will pass and be shown on green, probably leading to believe it's already done when is not the case. A similar effect can be achieved just using  `self notYetImplemented`

I would probably start doing something like this with my incomplete methods:

```
MyIncompleteMethod

  self flag: #toImplement.  
  self notYetImplemented.`
```

Comment: And in Pharo 8 we will integrate a new tool to browse flags ;)

Answer (score 12):

Methods whose implementation is still pending should send the `notYetImplemented` message like this:

```
methodImNotSureHowToImplement
  ^self notYetImplemented
```

if the unimplemented message gets sent anyway, it will signal a `NotYetImplemented` exception which will know the offending selector, `#methodImNotSureHowToImplement` in my example.

Note also that this will make it easy finding all methods that need to be implemented as senders of `#notYetImplemented`.

The implementation of `#notYetImplemented` is straightforward, thanks to the existence of `NotYetImplemented`.

```
notYetImplemented
  "Announce that this message is not yet implemented"
   NotYetImplemented signalFor: thisContext sender selector
```

Note also that `NotYetImplemented` is one of the subclasses of `SelectorException` which model several situations of similar kinds:

```
SelectorException
  NotYetImplemented
  PrimitiveFailed
  ShouldBeImplemented
  ShouldNotImplement
  SubclassResponsibility
```

Answer (score 1):

you also can use pragmas to mark such methods

Answer (score 0):

As Smalltalk provides the origin of agile development, let me provide a different answer. In a failing unit test. As you are not supposed to have a lot of those, it automatically provides the pressure to limit work in progress (the number of open #toDo's).